# DRF h2o r2 meanings

Tags: python, h2o

I created a model using a python script and after that, I run the following instructions:

```
print(rfmodel.model_performance(test_data=train).r2())
print(rfmodel.model_performance(test_data=test).r2())
```

Then, I get:

```
0.8875126069766902
0.7730216155314876
```

If I load the same model in Flow, in Training Metrics I see r2=0.776610.

What´s the difference between python first instruction r2 and Flow r2?

Comment: can you please post screen shots of what steps you are taking in Flow and which cell you are looking at to see the training metrics in Flow? Since the model object is in the java backend, you should get the exact same results whether calling the model performance from python or flow. Also if you want to compare the two use `rfmodel.model_performance(train = True).r2()` instead of `rfmodel.model_performance(test_data=train).r2()`

Answer (score 0):

The training metrics whether you get them through Flow or the Python API should be the same.

One explanation could be that the frame was rebalanced for model training. You would need to take a look at your logs and see if says anything like `INFO: Rebalancing train dataset into 8 chunks.` which indicates rebalancing or `train dataset already contains 32 (non-empty)  chunks. No need to rebalance.` which indicates there wasn't rebalancing. In general the numbers you get from `model.model_performance(test_data=train).r2()` and `model.r2(train=True)` (which is likely the equivalent to the training metric in Flow you were referring to) should be the same as long as the number of CPUs is the same and the frame has the same layout.